# How to replace one instance of a character in a string and put the output in a text box with the VB language

Tags: vb.net, random, replace

We are trying to only replace the first instance of "a" to `first second third`. Then it should loop and replace the second instance of "a" to a new generated value of `first second third` and continue this loop til there are no more "a" characters left and each "a" is a different value. However the results of the output are not correct. The code is erasing all characters before the last "a" then replacing that last "a".

```
    Dim message As String
    Dim start As Integer = 1
    Dim letterfinder As String
    Dim timesLooped As Integer = 1
    Dim length As Integer

    Dim first As Integer
    Dim second As Integer
    Dim third As Integer
    Dim count As Integer = 1

    message = inputBox.Text
    length = Len(message)
    timesLooped = 0
  While length > timesLooped
        Dim random As New Random
        letterfinder = Mid$(message, start, 1)
        If letterfinder = "a" Then
            first = random.Next(3, 9)
            second = 1 \ first
            third = 1 - second
            outputBox.Text = Replace(message, letterfinder, first & second & third, [start], [count])
        End If
        timesLooped = timesLooped + 1
        start = start + 1
    End While
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of an input the the desired output?

Comment: Input= "abaca" Output="301b401c601" The gui is setup with two textboxes one textbox is the input textbox while the other textbox is the output textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output.text box is just showing the final result (the interim changes happen too fast to see).  Add a listbox to watch the progress:

```
   If letterfinder = "a" Then
       first = random.Next(3, 9)
       second = 1 \ first
       third = 1 - second

       Dim res As String = Replace(message, letterfinder, _
                   first & second & third, [start], [count])
       txtOutput.Text = res
       ListBox1.Items.Add(timesLooped.ToString & vbTab & res)
   End If


Replace(message, "a", first & second & third, [start], [count])
```

is returning a substring STARTING at start... it does not substitute and return the whole thing.  The result of the 2nd pass for `abaca` is `701ca`.  A listbox will show you that.
For `ababfdsfac` Replace results in:

1. 701babfdsfac
2. 801bfdsfac
3. 301c

you get just the part from the current Start value on

EDIT

Here is a loop that does what you want.  I used VB6 type methods since the OP code was much more that style than .Net

```
    Dim first As Integer
    Dim result As String = ""
    Dim random As New Random
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()

    For n As Integer = 1 To Len(message)
        If Mid$(message, n, 1) = "a" Then

            first = random.Next(3, 9)
            result = result & CStr(first)
            result = result & CStr(1 \ first)               ' always 0
            result = result & CStr(1 - (1 \ first))         ' always 1
        Else
            result = result & Mid$(message, n, 1)

        End If

        txtOutput.Text = result
        ListBox1.Items.Add(result)                  ' post interim results
    Next
```

HTH

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the problem. We are not replacing it within the same string. We are creating a new string composed of the old string except with the "a" values replaced with the randomly generated "first second third" for each "a" there should be a different "first second third".

Comment: See my edit...and yes I did.  In each pass or substitution event you are only returning a part of the original string starting at the point of the current 'a'.

Comment: Fantastic solution sorry it took me so long to up vote it but I have tested it and it functions perfectly. Thank you for your help Plutonix!

Answer (score 0):

```
DIM randomNum = Function(i)
                  Dim r as new Random(3,9)
                  Dim num = String.Format("{0}01",r.Next().ToString)
                  Return num
                End Function

Dim output as new StringBuilder()

inputText.
    ToCharArray().
    ToList().
    ForEach(Sub(c)
              if c.equals("a"c) Then 
                  output.Append(randomNum())
              Else
                  output.Append(c)
              End If)
txtOutput.Text = output.ToString()
```

Comment: he/she/they are not changing the input.  That threw me too.

Comment: Its still only doing the last "a". Here is the result after using your code: Input = "ababfdsfac" Output = "801c" what the Output should be is something like Output= "801b601bfdsf901c"

Comment: `Replace` returns a substring starting at `[start]`.  See my new edit.

Comment: Your last comment helped me better understand the issue at hand. Thanks.